# Programmatic access to the Resque failed-job queue

Tags: ruby, resque

How can I write code to go through the Resque failure queue and selectively delete jobs? Right now I've got a handful of important failures there, interspersed between thousands of failures from a runaway job that ran repeatedly. I want to delete the ones generated by the runaway job. The only API I'm familiar with is for enqueuing jobs.  (I'll continue RTFMing, but I'm in a bit of a hurry.)

Comment: May not be what you want to hear but going directly to Redis and altering data that way may be the best move.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can manually modify the Failure queue the way you're asking, but it might be better to write a custom Failure handler that delete/re-enqueues jobs as they fail.

You can find the base failure backend [here](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/failure/base.rb) and an implementation that logs failed jobs to the Hoptoad exception tracking service [here](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/failure/thoughtbot.rb).

For example:

```
module Resque
  module Failure
    class RemoveRunaways < Base
      def save
        i=0
        while job = Resque::Failure.all(i)
          # Selectively remove all MyRunawayJobs from failure queue whenever they fail
          if job.fetch('payload').fetch('class') == 'MyRunawayJob'
            remove(i) 
          else
            i = i + 1
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention how to specify this backend to handle Failures.

In your Resque initializer (eg: config/initializers/resque.rb):

```
# Use Resque Multi failure handler: standard handler and your custom handler
Resque::Failure::Multiple.classes = [Resque::Failure::Redis, Resque::Failure::RemoveRunaways]
Resque::Failure.backend = Resque::Failure::Multiple
```

Answer (score 8):

I neded up doing it like this:

```
# loop over all failure indices, instantiating as needed  
(Resque::Failure.count-1).downto(0).each do |error_index_number|     

  failure = Resque::Failure.all(error_index_number)

  # here :failure is the hash that has all the data about the failed job, perform any check you need here      

  if failure["error"][/regex_identifying_runaway_job/].present?        
    Resque::Failure.remove(error_index_number)
    # or
    # Resque::Failure.requeue(error_index_number)
  end
```

As @Winfield mentioned, having a look at [Resque's failure backend](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/failure/base.rb) is useful.

Answer (score 0):

### Remove with bool function example

I used a higher order function approach, that evaluates a failure to remove

```
    def remove_failures(should_remove_failure_func)
      (Resque::Failure.count-1).downto(0).each do |i|
        failure = Resque::Failure.all(i)
        Resque::Failure.remove(i) if should_remove_failure_func.call(failure)
      end
    end

    def remove_failed_validation_jobs
      has_failed_for_validation_reason = -> (failure) do
        failure["error"] == "Validation failed: Example has already been taken"
      end
      remove_failures(has_failed_for_validation_reason)
    end
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.